# Office365/Sharepoint Online: Internal server error against the change events API call

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm getting the following error against the API call that fetches the change logs for a OneDrive User

```
{"error_description":
    "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  
    For more information about the error, either turn on 
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from 
    the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the 
    exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the 
    Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}
```

My question is, how do I enable the trace for my Office365 subscription? as that's Sharepoint Online.

The API call

```
POST
https://<mysitecollection>/personal/some_user_domain_com/_api/web/getchanges
```

Please note that this tenant is NOT on the shared cloud for Office365.